# Where should I ask questions about recommendations for software components

Tags: discussion

I've seen many questions being closed on SO because they ask for recommendations on which components to use because it is often a matter of opinion.

I know this may also be the wrong place, but where *should* I ask?

It takes so much time to read up on every components (just to find that at least half of them are outdated or just never took off) and write some software to try every remaining available component out...

Comment: If it's a pure recommendation you're looking for, Stack Exchange is not the place. There is no appropriate site within the network. Perhaps http://www.slant.co/ is a better fit for you?

Comment: StackExchange isn't a recommendations site, it's a Q&A site so those questions don't really fit well here. If you were to ask such a question and someone finds it 3 years from now it's unlikely that the answers you received at the time would be of any use to the new visitor. We play the long game here - not just instant gratification!

Comment: As you mentioned "just to find that at least half of them are outdated", same could be the case with answers on Stack Exchange which were provided on a recommendation questions. Which is the reason, most Stack Exchange sites avoid such questions.

Comment: Well, Drupal Answers have it easier - Drupal's politic is to always try and join efforts, making one module for one task. That frees questions about modules from to much pooling (usually there is 0 or 1 real answer), but even there they are not liked to much.

Comment: Software recommendations  ( http://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/44877/software-recommendations ) from the duplicate question above seems like it may be a good place. I think there will always be this kind of questions and it is good to create a space for them!